# Expansion wave in PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The book I'm using is "Applied partial differential equations" written by Richard Haberman. 
On page 556, he gives the definition of expansion waves as

"The distance between

$$p(_{x_{1}},0)$$

and

$$p(_{x_{2}},0)$$

for some $${x_{1}}>{x_{2}}$$ as increasing.

This sounds very ambiguous and not at all clear. What is 'distance'? Is it the gradient between 2 $x$-intervals that corresponds to some $u(x,t)$? Some clearer explanation would really help.

**Edit:**

I think I might have some insights into the definition which might possibly aid anyone in the future. PDEs can be rather tricky with the rather vague definitions.

Going back to the question, suppose for simplicity there are 2 lines of finite length emanating from the origin (emanating from the origin is not a necessary condition) with one more being steeper than the other. These two lines diverges as time $t$ increases.

Let's suppose the two lines are given as $x=6t$ and $x=8t$. At some infinitesimally small time, the distance between the two lines are infinitesimally small. As time, $t$, grows, the distance-if we draw a horizontal straight line connecting between these 2 lines at different frames time increases-increases.